# auto-fill and minmax() don't work when items are not the same size

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a fully responsive grid with different-sized items.

[This example](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/GZQYOL) works fine with

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) ) ;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i">I</div>
</div>
```

All items are the same size and on the smallest screen size they line up on top of each other.

Now if you try the same with [this example](https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/GZQYQa) the items that have left the explicit grid and have to move again are not doing so but are shrinking under the specified minmax value. So on the smallest screen size some items cannot be seen.

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.k {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}

.g {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i">I</div>
  <div class="box j">J</div>
  <div class="box k">K</div>
  <div class="box l">L</div>
  <div class="box m">M</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get example 2 to behave like example 1, other than adding a media-query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big hint to the answer in what you wrote:

> *Now if you try the same with this example, the items that have left the explicit grid and have to move again are not doing so but are shrinking under the specified `minmax` value.*

**"...the items that have left the explicit grid..."**

This is why your grid items are shrinking below the `minmax` minimum set in `grid-template-columns`.

Once you're not in the *explicit grid*, you're in the *implicit grid*, and the `grid-template-columns` property has no effect.

The explicit grid is defined by [three properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids):

- `grid-template-columns`
- `grid-template-rows`
- `grid-template-areas`

Tracks in the implicit grid ignore these properties. Instead, they are sized using `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns`.

The default value of `grid-auto-columns` is `auto`, which is why your grid items shrink to content size when they exit the explicit grid.

Try this:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) ) ;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr); /* NEW */
}
```

Then, optionally, to [make the grid fill empty cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45016555/3597276) when re-sizing, add this, too:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr) ) ;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr); /* NEW */
    grid-auto-flow: dense; /* NEW */
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, 1fr);  /* NEW */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;   /* NEW */
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.a {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}

.k {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}

.g {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
  <div class="box g">G</div>
  <div class="box h">H</div>
  <div class="box i">I</div>
  <div class="box j">J</div>
  <div class="box k">K</div>
  <div class="box l">L</div>
  <div class="box m">M</div>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPymEy)

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B, I can see there's no "magic" workaround for this as of now. I'll consider this question answered, even though your solution only part-solves the issue. Items keep their size, but still do not wrap all the way on the smallest screen size.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is no, you can't. The reason is that when you combine `auto-fill` and `minmax(200px, 1fr)` you are telling to the browser rendering your code to make grid with columns with the minimum with of 200px and the maximum of 1fr. Then you are telling to your boxes to span 2 or 3 columns which means that they have minimum width of at least 400px or 600px on the big screen. On smaller screens, span rule starts to lose its meaning but auto does not take over. It still has to calculate width of individual columns taking into account individual width differences of `.a .b .c` etc.

So, unfortunately, you would need to use media queries or find some other type of layout.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying